# require_once is failing

Tags: php

I'm about to go crazy. Have no idea why it keeps failing.

```
index.php
chdir(__DIR__);
if(!defined('ARCTICA_CORE_DIR'))
    define('ARCTICA_CORE_DIR', './arctica/core/');

require_once(ARCTICA_CORE_DIR . 'Arctica.php');

echo ARCTICA_CORE_DIR -> Correctly outputs ./arctica/core/

BUUUUUUT;

Warning: require_once(./arctica/core/Arctica.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Arctica\index.php on line 18
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './arctica/core/Arctica.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\Arctica\index.php on line 18
```

OS is Windows 7.

This is the path of my application:

```
C:\wamp\www\Arctica\index.php
```

This is the path of file I'm trying to require:

```
C:\wamp\www\Arctica\arctica\core\Arctica.php
```

What's wrong? Am I missing something? I bet it is something little I overlook...

Comment: Have you tried using the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant instead of hardcoding /

Comment: do: `echo ARCTICA_CORE_DIR . 'Arctica.php';` and you know what the problem is.

Comment: What are the permissions of Artica.php? Is it readable?

Comment: @1; Yes. Tried. @2; Tried. Same output. @3; File permissions are correct. @4; Full access.

Comment: @Lisa, Have you tried "hardcoding" the filename in require_once function ?

Comment: you can check with `realpath()` if the relative path is resolved correctly.

Comment: @sh4nx0r; Going to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was having a second unnecessary .php extension. `Arctica.php.php.`

Windows 7 didn't show the file extension. I've noticed it when I copied my files into linux environment.

Answer (score 2):

possibly `C:\wamp\www\Arctica\arctica` is not in your include path. Says `(include_path='.;C:\php\pear')`. You can find out with `echo get_include_path();` and you can add your own path to it using [`set_include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

Really not needed to start playing with `chdir();` for this purpose.

Also I would remove the dot.

`define('ARCTICA_CORE_DIR', '/arctica/core/');`

and then why not just use the full path?

```
define('ARCTICA_CORE_DIR', __DIR__.'/arctica/core/');
```

Comment: I've never relied on set_include_path before. Every application used to work properly. I'll try your solution. Edit: Still the same. "Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\Arctica/arctica/core/Arctica.php): failed to open stream:"